# My password generator is consistently losing characters each time it is run

Tags: python, loops, password-generator

I'm fairly new to back-end programming and have been given the assignment to create a simple password generator using nothing but loops. The program prompts the user to decide how many letters, numbers, and symbols they wish to include in their password. In order to generate passwords wherein these characters would be inserted in a random order, I implemented a list for each type of character to correspond to. The "randKey" variable picks one of these keys at random and calls a function that inserts a character based on its value. When the variable representing the number of characters the user wishes to enter is less than 0, the key is removed from the list. For some reason, whenever I run this specific algorithm, the program produces less than the desired number of characters. Can you help me figure out why this is?

I tried changing values such as the range of the loop itself, but it proved completely inconsequential.

Edit:
I'm also aware that I could have just shuffled the characters around in the password, but I wanted to see if I could get this particular method to work just to determine whether or I would be capable of implementing it.

```
# Password Generator
import random

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

characters = [[letters],[numbers],[symbols]]

numLetters = int(input("How many letters would you like to include? "))
numSymbols = int(input("How many symbols would you like to include? "))
numNums = int(input("How many numbers would you like to include? "))

totalLen = numLetters + numSymbols + numNums

pswd = ""

# Each of these functions will be called by another function in a random order.
def addLetter():
    return letters[random.randint(0, len(letters) - 1)]

def addNumber():
    return numbers[random.randint(0, len(numbers) - 1)]

def addSymbol():
    return symbols[random.randint(0, len(symbols) - 1)]

# When an "add" function is called, it will evaluate whether or not the "num--" variable is greater than 0 in order
# to determine if it should go through.
keys = ["a", "b", "c"]

for i in range(totalLen - 1):
    randKey = keys[random.randint(0, len(keys) - 1)]
    if randKey == "a":
        if numLetters > 0:
            pswd += addLetter()
            numLetters -= 1
        else:
            keys.pop(0)
    elif randKey == "b":
        if numSymbols > 0:
            pswd += addSymbol()
            numSymbols -= 1
        else:
            keys.pop(1)
    elif randKey == "c":
        if numNums > 0:
            pswd += addNumber()
            numNums -= 1
        else:
            keys.pop(2)

print(pswd)
```

Comment: why do you add the pop

Comment: I don't know for certain but I think you'll find that you can't rely on the keys popping since if a or b is removed first then the other 2 pop indices are wrong, maybe `keys.pop(keys.index('a'))` would help

Comment: I think you meant to shuffle `keys` and iterate over them. The calls to `pop()` will surely remove the wrong items.

Comment: You randomly select whether to add a letter, symbol or number. _Then_ you check whether you've already added enough of this category. If you did, you remove this kind of "key". That means, the key will only get removed when there are already enough of this key, _and the key gets chosen again._ The action of removing the key takes up where usually one character should be added to the password.

Comment: @LiterallyGutsFromBerserk The idea was that it would keep the program from evaluating redundant character types after they had already been fully implemented

Comment: Just generate a list of letters, symbols and numbers, however many the user requested of each, in one list, shuffle the list, then join it together.

Comment: @deceze Thank you. Just now I tried that, but my implementation of it doesn't seem to have worked. Maybe I've just done it wrong

Comment: Then the easier fix is to change that `if..else` which removes the keys. Just add a letter/symbol/number, decrease the count, *then* check if the count has reached 0 and pop the key immediately.

Comment: *"using nothing but loops"* — You're already using quite a bit more than just loops here. What exactly isn't "a loop" anymore…?

Comment: @deceze doesn't it already chack if it has reached 0 in the if?

Comment: @deceze Well, loops and some of the knowledge we've gathered thus far. I only included some basic functions in order to keep the code from becoming more cluttered than it already is

Comment: @Literally Yes, but on *the next possible iteration*, which is what's causing the missing characters. Current logic: if "number" gets chosen, either add a number, _or_ remove "numbers" as a valid choice. Correct logic: if "number" gets chosen, add a number, then if all numbers have been used up, remove "numbers" as valid choice.

Comment: Thanks to @deceze for the suggestions; I finally (pretty positive) am done with edits on my answer now; that should be close to as optimal and readable and fast ("pythonic") approach, as sufficient for your assignment, I imagine. Also a good illustration of the many different ways a program and its algorithm can be designed (and how four eyes are better than 2 )

Comment: @John Did you just call me "four eyes"?! ;-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you state you are interested in your particular algorithmic approach, but, if it's of any help, here is a much simpler and more foolproof approach, too:

```py
import itertools
import random
import string

letters = string.ascii_lowercase
numbers = string.digits
symbols = ["!", "#", "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", "*", "+"]

characters = [letters, numbers, symbols]

n_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like to include? "))
n_numbers = int(input("How many numbers would you like to include? "))
n_symbols = int(input("How many symbols would you like to include? "))

user_inputs = [n_letters, n_numbers, n_symbols]

pswd = [random.choices(x, k=y) for (x, y) in zip(characters, user_inputs)]

pswd = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(pswd))
pswd = "".join(random.sample(pswd, k=len(pswd)))

print(pswd)
print(len(pswd))
```

```
How many letters would you like to include? 10
How many numbers would you like to include? 3
How many symbols would you like to include? 1
fx*m2wnyiu63ib
14
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a while loop to ensure you pick a symbole every iteration like this

```
for i in range(totalLen):
    current_len = len(pswd)
    while current_len == len(pswd):
        randKey = keys[random.randint(0, len(keys) - 1)]
        if randKey == "a":
            if numLetters > 0:
                pswd += addLetter()
                numLetters -= 1
            else:
                keys.remove("a")
        elif randKey == "b":
            if numSymbols > 0:
                pswd += addSymbol()
                numSymbols -= 1
            else:
                keys.remove("b")
        elif randKey == "c":
            if numNums > 0:
                pswd += addNumber()
                numNums -= 1
            else:
                keys.remove("c")
```

Comment: Thank you to no end. This has helped me immensely, both in regards to fixing the program and to better understanding loops

Comment: This is an overcomplicated fix for an already overcomplicated algorithm.